# laravel pdf file download from ajax request (laravel 5)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, pdf, download

My html code is like this :

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showAjaxPdf('{{ $row->file_path }}');"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a>
```

My javascript code is like this :

```
function showAjaxPdf(file_path)
        {
            var file_path = file_path.replace(/\\/g,"/");
            //example : file_path = assets/images/myfile.pdf
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: 'file_path=' + file_path,
                url: "news/test",
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#test').html(response);

                }
            });
        }
```

My function test in controller :

```
public function postTest(Request $request)
    {
$file_path = $request->input('file_path');  
        return response()->download($file_path);       
    }
```

When I click on the pdf icon, no response.

I wish, when click on the pdf icon, appear like this:

[image]

how to keep when click pdf icon, the image appears like it?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @user3158900, I think it is not the same. My problem in ajax response.  `success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#test').html(response);

                }`

Comment: @user3158900, The response seems wrong.

Comment: Your controller is attempting to return a file download.  You are taking that response and attempting to set it as html on the page.  It's very hard to tell what you actually want.  You want the user to be able to download the pdf file to their machine or do you want the contents of the pdf itself to appear somewhere on the page?

Comment: @user3158900, Thank you for answering my question. I want the user to be able to download the pdf file to their machine.

Comment: definitely a duplicate of the above question :-D

Comment: @user3158900, @Adrian Tombu, I change javascript like this : `function showAjaxPdf(file_path){
                $.post("news/test", { file_path: file_path } ); 
            }`. But still no success to download pdf or displays like this image : http://imgur.com/uhPfOWL

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is, written two separate route one to verify and one to download.
On success of one ajax I have triggered window.open(downloadUrl,'_blank') to download in separete window.
It is not the way asked but it prevents any upcoming errors as verify url will sort that

```
$.ajax({
            url: verifyUrl,  
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            data: null,
            error: function (err){$('#ajax_loader_div').hide();},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#ajax_loader_div').hide();
                if (response.status == 'success') 
                {

                    window.open(downloadUrl,'_blank');

                }else if(response.status == 'error') 
                {
                    //show error
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to set the header with response object. 
Please see the below code.

```
    $headers = array(
                  'Content-Type'=> 'application/pdf'
                );
$file_path = $request->input('file_path');  
 //TODO: you have to split the file name from url 
 return Response::download($file_path, '<filename>', $headers);
```

I hope this code will help you

Answer (score 0):

return `Response::download($file_path, '<filename>', $headers);`

It's return response, not download file!